# Criteria API to build dynamic query in spring-data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a List which I use to find some id's from the db. The list contains something like below:

```
List<someObject> filterCriteria =[{"name":"somename", "value":"someValue"},{"value":"randomValue"}]
```

This gives me two separate filters one searching with nameValue and other only with value .
I build two Criteria using this values :
Name value criteria :

```
where("person.name")
                .is(filterItem.getName())
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("person.value").regex(filterItem.getValue(), "i"))
```

And value filter as :

```
where("person.value")
                .regex(someString, "i");
```

I iterate in a separate service to receive these as a list of Criteria's as :

```
List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
       filterCriteria.forEach(x -> criteriaList.add(criteriaMapper.mapFilterCriteria()));
```

I am trying to use the Criteria API in spring to build a single query which is equivalent to the mongo query with the above criteria's

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{$and:[{"person.value":"jOfQIv5QMairziy"}
,{"person.name":"zzDLpQSBAA"}]},{"person.value":"re3bMfZAIDZHFPj"}]});
```

I am unable to form the write query. I came across the QueryBuilder API but cannot wrap my head around how to use it. 
Any help would be very helpful

Comment: Why do you need to use `regex` if mongo query doesn't mention regex at all?

Comment: The value field is matched by regex, which is not reflected in the mongo query. What i was looking is a some ideas on how to tie these two filter queries together with the or operator, while inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `$elemMatch` which meets better your requirement:

```
List<someObject> filterCriteria =[{"name":"somename", "value":"someValue"},{"value":"randomValue"}];
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<Criteria>();

for(someObject filterItem: filterCriteria) {
    //You may impement condition: If name not exists, put only value
    //Criteria.where("person").elemMatch(
    //    Criteria.where("value").is(filterItem.getName())
    //);
    criterias.add(
        Criteria.where("person").elemMatch(
            Criteria.where("name").is(filterItem.getName())
                .and("value").is(filterItem.getValue())
        )
    );
}

Query query   = Query.query(new Criteria().orOperator(
                    criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.length])));
List<SomeClass> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, SomeClass.class);
```

---

### Is equivalent to

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "person": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "value": "jOfQIv5QMairziy"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "name": "zzDLpQSBAA",
          "value": "re3bMfZAIDZHFPj"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks ! .toArray() did the trick for me to get the right query.